# spring-cloud-sleuth one of the microserives out of three does not show the spanid, and token id in logs after adding dependency

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using `http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_adding_to_the_project` for adding Spring Cloud Sleuth without the Zipkin integration

But in one of the microserives out of three, `does not show the spanid, and token id in logs` after adding dependency for all services (all are http request services, though there are couple of more services which require JMS - on which I need to work)

Service1

```
2016-06-05 17:12:45.404  INFO [my-service1-id,73b62c0f90d11e06,73b62c0f90d11e06,false] 85184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.MyService1MakingARequest
```

Service2

```
2016-06-05 17:12:45.404  INFO 85185 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.MyService2MakingARequest
```

Service3

```
2016-06-05 17:12:45.404  INFO [my-service3-id,73b62c0f90d11e06,73b62c0f90d11e06,false] 85185 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.MyService3MakingARequest
```

Experts, Please suggest what can be done to see the effect in Service2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to show your sample project. Another is to check if you don't have a custom logback.xml or any other type of logging configuration that breaks the current set up (most likely you do cause I can see that the pattern is different).